# Meteor ReactiveVar behaviour?

Tags: meteor

I use ReactiveVar to extend the subscription when the user reach the end of the page but I experienced some strange behaviours lately (might be because some package updates?)

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function(){
    var tpl = this;

    tpl.dict = new ReactiveDict();
    tpl.var = new ReactiveVar();
    Session.set('session', undefined);

    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        console.log(tpl.dict.get('foo'), tpl.var.get(), Session.get('session'));
    })
});

Template.hello.onRendered(function(){
    var tpl = this;

    console.log(this.dict.get('foo'), this.var.get(), Session.get('session'));

    tpl.dict.set('foo', 'foo');
    tpl.var.set('foo');
    Session.set('session', 'foo');
});
```

This gives:

```
undefined undefined undefined (onCreated)
undefined undefined undefined (onRendered)
foo foo foo (onCreated, after autorun)
```

My basic question is: is this supposed to be the normal behaviour? The ReactiveVar/Dict aren't supposed to autorun automatically when changed?

Any idea on this or am I just dumb? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly expected behavior. `onCreated` fires before `onRendered` and only at the very end of `onRendered` are you setting any values to your variables. And yes, only code that is in an autorun block (implicitly or explicitly) will rerun when dependencies change. `onRendered` and `onCreated` themselves are not reactive (unlike, e.g., template helpers).